# JsonProperty based on webconfig

Tags: .net, json

I have a question about JsonProperty on the field.

Is it possible to pass a propertyName from WebConfig?

I need it for my application because I have two different "types":

production -> use for clients
test -> use for developers.

In my webconfig in-app settings I want to set JsonProperty name, something like this:

```
[JsonProperty(value from app settings)]

<appSettings>
    <add key="Version" value="test" /> or value="production"
</appSettings>
```

Is there any option for doing this?

Comment: Short answer: No. Not so short answer `JsonPropertyAttribute` is metadata for the adorned member. Cant be changed on the fly. You may need to change your approach. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a custom attribute that inherits from JsonProperty and add a parameter for the App setting NAME, rather than the VALUE. Then in the logic of the attribute, wherever you need it,  you could pull the value of the App setting that it was set to.

Not as elegant as you would have hoped, but attribute parameters need to be resolved at compile time, meaning constants.

Comment: `JsonPropertyAttribute` is sealed and therefore cannot be inherited.